# Total multiple columns for multiple teams & groups

Tags: excel, if-statement, intersection, named-ranges

I need to total the teams A B C D for Girls & Boys However the order of the teams changes each week, so I can not do a simple:

> GIRLS TEAM A = B3+G3
>   GIRLS TEAM B = C3+H3

```
    A       B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I
1           Saturday        Sunday          
2           A   B   C   D   A   B   C   D
3   Girls   3   4   4   2   8   3   6   2
4   Boys    2   4   6   3   6   4   6   5
```

I can not use VLOOKUP; will not work due to the team names being vertical.
I have also tried Using Named Ranges & Intersection (SPACE) Operator however this doesn't work with each team name appearing twice.

Can you offer any suggestions? The lay out can not be amended.

Comment: I'm guessing the example is flawed.  Girls Team A = B3 + G3, according to the example should be B3 + F3, but that still doesn't tell us WHERE this formula even exists.  Where are you putting that result, and the boys?  Please include more of the layout.  If you can get a screenshot posted to an image hosting service and include it, that would go a long way to understanding, since your layout can't be changed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` to get the total for `Girls` in `Team A`, e.g. using your example

`=SUMPRODUCT((B2:I2="A")*(A3:A4="Girls"),B3:I4)`

If you always know that girls will be row 3 then `SUMIF` would be sufficient, i.e.

`=SUMIF(B2:I2,"A",B3:I3)`

Comment: That's a nice function.  I've never used it before.  When you come to this site to try and answer questions, you learn something new every day.